# Images from my website won't load in mobile browsers

Tags: android, html, image, load

I'm building a REALLY basic 'Hello World' HTML/CSS site to get used to coding from scratch (previously I relied heavily on Dreamweaver trial and error!).

Everything was looking great on my laptop but I wanted to test how the site looked on a mobile browser, so I saved the site folder to my Dropbox and tried to load the home page from my Android phone.

The page loads perfectly but the one image I have doesn't - I just get the alt text. This is the case for both Android's native browser and Opera mobile.

I have tried both .jpg and .gif file types, and also adding in a fixed width, height and border value as suggested on another thread here (this changes the shape of the alt text placeholder but that's all). I did also add a '/' at the tail of the `<img>` tag, again to no avail.

I'm amazed that this is a problem for such a basic page, but I have triple-checked all my code in the textbook I'm using, so I'm not sure what to do except post here!

The HTML for the image concerned is as follows:

```
<div id="banner"><img src="750x262PxBanner.gif" width="100%" alt="banner"></div>
```

I have no CSS for this div beyond `padding-top: 10px`, and the image is in the same folder as the page it's on - as I say this is a VERY basic site, and it looks fine on my laptop!

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: And the "load pictures" option is enabled in the browsers?

Comment: They load pictures from every other website, so I'd have to assume so...

Answer (score 1):

Try to access the picture's URL from your `smartphone`, and check if the image loads correctly (acces the `.../750x262PxBanner.gif` instead of `.../index.html`): maybe the URI is incorrect for the smartphone, or the file format isn't supported.

Rename the picture to avoid case sensitiveness (use lower case only for instance).

Else, try not to start the picture's name with **`[0-9]`**.

Comment: What file formats ARE supported by Opera for Android and the native Android browser? I was under the impression that .jpg and .gif are the best options for maximum compatibility, along with .png.

Comment: @user2342949 I don't know the whole list of supported images formats, but jpg, png and gif has **several variants**, like indexed, greyscale or RGB(A) colors, compression... You may have used some of these variants in your picture, one that Opera/Android doesn't recognize. Try to directly access to the picture  and check if the smartphone recognize the format (and the variants) you used. If not, don't use exotics variants and stay at RGB colors, uncompressed pictures.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. Try giving width and height of that image in pixels and re-check. Like this `<img src="750x262PxBanner.gif" width="750px" height="262px" alt="banner">`
   (doesn't makes too much sense, but may work in rarest of scenarios)
2. Try putting the absolute image path to know whether loading is an issue or not.
3. Try renaming the image to banner or something without numbers. (Again, really doesn't make great sense, but may or may not work)
4. Try to host files with some hosting or upload the same on some FTP

Comment: You should have written this as a comment. StackOverflow follows a Q&A scheme; it's not a discussion forum.

Comment: Ok so I tried <div id="banner"><img src="750x262PxBanner.gif" width="750" height="262" alt="banner"></div> - same problem as before, it just resizes the placeholder.

Comment: user2342949 - `<img src="750x262PxBanner.gif" width="750px" height="262px" alt="banner">` - Updated code

Comment: @ClassStacker - I have updated my answer and commented the same as a reply to the user2342949.

Comment: Tried 1 and 3, separately and simultaneously - nothing. As for the absolute file path, that changes depending on if I access the files from my mobile dropbox or my laptop dropbox, hence not wanting to use it. As I said before, the image file is in the same folder as the html file for the page, and the rest of the page loads fine including linking into the CSS (a separate file in that folder).